# Круговая траектория движения курсора

Tags: wpf, вёрстка, gui, интерфейс, ui

Есть кнопка. Нажатие с удержанием вызывают событие, в котором можно узнать координаты курсора. Каким образом выяснить в какую сторону движется курсор: по часовой или против?

Имеется ввиду движение типа кругового или спирального, важно лишь направление движения.

Поправьте, если путаюсь.

Comment: Запоминать предыдущие координаты и анализировать

Comment: @АндрейNOP, по какому признаку делать анализ?

Comment: А это уже другой, но не менее интересный, вопрос. Возможно вам стоит создать новый вопрос с соответствующими метками ([алгоритм] м.б.). Либо отредактировать этот, если вам понятно как реализовать это в WPF .